# Asynchronous reading books in array with promise method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

hello so I'm learning Asynchronous javascript, and I'm having problem to call promise function. there are promise.js and index.js in the index it calls the readBooksPromise function. The book that will be spent is the book in the books array. function readBooksPromise accepts input time which is **10000 ms (10 seconds)** and books at **index 0**. After getting the resolve, the remaining time is **decreased**, the remaining time is used to read the book at index 1. And so on until the time runs out. **Looping is prohibited here**. Thank you

```
// promise.js
function readBooksPromise(time, book) {
  console.log(`i start reading ${book.name}`);
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      let remainingTime = time - book.timeSpent;
      if (remainingTime >= 0) {
        console.log(`i've finished reading ${book.name}, my time now ${remainingTime} left`);
        resolve(remainingTime);
      } else {
        console.log(`i dont have time to read ${book.name}`);
        reject(remainingTime);
      }
    }, book.timeSpent);
  });
}

module.exports = readBooksPromise;
```

```
var readBooksPromise = require("./promise.js");

var books = [
  { name: "LOTR", timeSpent: 3000 },
  { name: "Fidas", timeSpent: 2000 },
  { name: "Calculus", timeSpent: 4000 },
  { name: "comics", timeSpent: 1000 },
];

// continue the code to call function readBooksPromise
```

Comment: *"I'm having problem to call promise function"*: that is very vague. What exactly is the problem you have in solving this exercise?

Comment: I suggest to close this question as the Asker is not responding and has not provided any trace of effort.